# Protecting Side-load UWP apps from distribution online

Tags: windows, uwp, store

If I want to give an appx app package to someone to sideload on a windows 10 pc with a developer account, is there any way to prevent the appx package from being distributed online?

When it is in the Windows store, the store handles payment and basic licensing. There is no strategy whereby I could revoke a side-loaded app???

Thanks...

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent" exactly? If you intend to deploy the app in the store you should submit an .appxupload. The .appx is only used to sideload the app on a device.

Comment: What I mean is that if I made the appx available to someone...e.g. say on a usb disk...if it was distributed online, there would be no license protection so anyone who wanted to acquire the app would bypass the store and sideload the pirate version. I was wondering if there is anything I could do to either make the sideloaded app licensed to the individual or somehow manage all sideloaded apps.

Comment: So I want anyway to allow sideloading of UWP app but to prevent it from running at a later date..does the windows app store have any features that will allow me to do this...if not then am I restricted to using 3rd part licensing systems outside the windows store...????

Answer (score 0):

The appx package doesn't provide anything for you to verify the usage of it. Anyone can install with your package.

But you can create your own account system by setup a server and ask your user to login to use your features. If they are not licensed user when you verify their account, you can disable the navigating behavior from your app to prevent they use your functions. This means although they can install your app, they may not able to use the functions you provided behind your verification. Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to deploy the app in the store you should submit an `.appxupload`. The `.appx` is only used to sideload the app on a device.

Of course anyone that has access to the `.appx` can do whatever they want with it - like for example side-loading it - just like they can do whatever they want with an `.exe`. There is no functionality within the `.appx` deployment technology that allows you to "revoke a side-loaded app" from an unknown computer that you don't have access to if that's what you are asking.

If you want to restrict the access to your app, or rather the app content, you should implement some kind of authentication and/or authorization within the app itself. You could for example connect to a remote service that grants access to user's at startup.